# Isometric involutions and sections

Tags: metric-spaces

I have a metric space $X$ and an isometric involution defined on it  $i:X\rightarrow X$. My intuiton tells me that I can find a (continous) section $s:X/i \rightarrow X$. Is this true? Any references where I might read about similar situations? (For example studying when do covering spaces have sections could be similar)

Comment: I haven't seen section used in that sense before, what would this mean with say $S^1$ and rotation by $\pi$?

Comment: Maybe I'm misusing the word. I want a continuous function $s:X/i \rightarrow X$ such that $\pi \circ s = id$, where $\pi$ is the canonical projection.

Comment: Sorry ignore my last comment, I think you may have to look at higher order spheres like $S^2$ and $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Comment: Actually no, there is no section which will work for $S^1$ and $S^1 / \{-1,1\}$.  If you continuously map $\{x,-x\}$ to $x$ or something, eventually you'll have two points not connected at the ends.

Comment: @muzzlator Why not post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the mapping of $S^1$ into $S^1 / \{-x, x\}$.  If we are to find a continuous section $s : S^1 / i \rightarrow S^1$, then because $S^1 / i$ is connected, the image must be too.  This means that you will get the image of $s$ being a semi-circle. Let $x_0$ be a point where the semicircle breaks.  Then $s$ isn't continuous at $\pi(x_0)$.